# How to limit a WooCommerce product title on specific devices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I’m looking forward on how can I limit a product title on different devices, for example: on pc “ a red Apple”, but when it changes to Mobile it shows like: “ a red app…”

Anyone know of it is possible?

I have tried different phps but I can only limit by words and characters but I would like it to limit depending of the device or breakpoint

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to do this using only PHP. PHP is running on server side, so it not knows what device (or resolution) client is using.

You should be able to achieve this using JavaScript, as you can get page width:

```
window.screen.availWidth
```

Which you can use to check if device is mobile or PC.

And then modify the text in for example div:

```
const divWithText = document.getElementyById('your_text_div')
const divText = divWithText.textContent()
const shortDivText = divText.substr(0, 10) // depends how long you want the text
divWithText.innerHTML(shortDivText)
```

It can be written shorter, but I wanted to make each step clear.

Comment: Thanks, is there any php so I can limit to certain words on product titles for: archives and relate products but that it doesn’t affect the single product title?

Comment: Yes, you can use the_title hook for this, but inside you need to distinguish if you are on a single product page. Something like that:

`if( 'product' !== get_post_type() ) { return $title } else { // do your substring }`